# Why does my ListView Items turn white automatically?

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I'm working on an app that's going to display roughly 25 items in a `ListView`. When the app loads, the first three items loads just fine, but the 4th one and some other ones are completely white and doesn't even turn to the color it's suppose to be. if I scroll down in the list and back up a couple of times, all of them turn white and they never return to their original color. Why is that and what can I do to prevent this? Should I use a different control to display the items?

I've set some of the properties to empty strings because I don't want to share that data to the public. Doing so does not effect the example at all, the binding works perfectly, just as it should.

This is what it looks like

[image]

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MaterialDesign.MVVM.ViewModel"
             x:Class="MaterialDesign.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:HomeViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Background="#282828">

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <Frame Background="#302E2E"
                               Margin="10,10,10,20"
                               Padding="0"
                               CornerRadius="4">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Image HeightRequest="200"
                                       Source="{Binding ThePicture}"
                                       Aspect="Fill"
                                       IsAnimationPlaying="True"/>

                                <StackLayout Margin="10">

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                           FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                           FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           FontFamily="RobotoMedium"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           FontFamily="RobotoMedium"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           TextColor="#929292"
                                           FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                    <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                                                BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource T}"
                                                Wrap="Wrap"
                                                Direction="row"
                                                FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                                AlignItems="Start"
                                                AlignContent="Start"
                                                Padding="0"
                                                Margin="0">

                                    </FlexLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Could you also post the code about "items" behind? Also could have a test with 5 or 6 static items in the list to see the result.

Comment: look at the caching settings for ListView, and consider switching to CollectionView

Comment: Hi, set CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"

Comment: Try to replace the Frame control with a Grid. Every time where I use the Frame i have a problem on UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a ListView as a repeater. You don't need the overhead of a ListView. You can read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-bindable-layout/)

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Background="#302E2E"
                   Margin="10,10,10,20"
                   Padding="0"
                   CornerRadius="4">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image HeightRequest="200"
                           Source="{Binding ThePicture}"
                           Aspect="Fill"
                           IsAnimationPlaying="True"/>

                    <StackLayout Margin="10">

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                               FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                               FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                         <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                FontFamily="RobotoMedium"
                                FontSize="20"
                                TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontFamily="RobotoMedium"
                               FontSize="20"
                               TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               TextColor="#929292"
                               FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                               Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                                    BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource T}"
                                   Wrap="Wrap"
                                   Direction="row"
                                   FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                   AlignItems="Start"
                                   AlignContent="Start"
                                   Padding="0"
                                   Margin="0">

                        </FlexLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
         </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
 </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Frame control.

Try the following code with the https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView

```
xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"


<yummy:PancakeView
            Background="#302E2E"
                           Margin="10,10,10,20"
                           Padding="0"
                           CornerRadius="4">
            <StackLayout>
                            <Image HeightRequest="200"
                                   Source="{Binding ThePicture}"
                                   Aspect="Fill"
                                   IsAnimationPlaying="True"/>

                            <StackLayout Margin="10">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                       FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                       FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       FontFamily="RobotoMedium"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       FontFamily="RobotoMedium"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       TextColor="#F9F9F9"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       TextColor="#929292"
                                       FontFamily="RobotoRegular"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                                <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                                            BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource T}"
                                            Wrap="Wrap"
                                            Direction="row"
                                            FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                            AlignItems="Start"
                                            AlignContent="Start"
                                            Padding="0"
                                            Margin="0">

                                </FlexLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
        </yummy:PancakeView>
```